# VSTS Build output with release management

Tags: azure

How can I use output of the Build process, artifacts, of VSTS with Release Management component?

Is it possible to customize Build Agents of VSTS – e.g. to you Chocolatey and how?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to publish artifacts in the Build component of the process and then at your Release definition you can create a link that monitors for outputs of a certain Build.